# Can Power BI users access a tooltip scrollbar

Tags: tooltip, powerbi

I have a tooltip that references a bar chart visualization with more rows than can be displayed at once. When I apply this tooltip to a report visual and hover over it I cannot click and drag the scrollbar without closing the tooltip itself, nor can I use my mouse's scrollwheel to slide the scrollbar either.

Apart from adding the tooltip visual to my report page, is there a setting or toggle to lock the tooltip in place or otherwise make the scrollbar usable in Power BI?

Comment: Perhaps use drillthrough instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-drillthrough

Comment: You can change the size of the tooltip window, though I haven't found any way to make the tooltip interactable.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft drillthroughs would work, but make it more difficult for at-a-glance reporting. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users currently cannot interact with objects on report page tooltips (scrolling, visuals like slicers, etc.). Best to resize the tooltip page height or re-think the visual (e.g. "Top 5" in bar chart only) to avoid the scrollbar if possible.

[More Info about that](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/how-do-users-access-the-scrollbar-on-report-page-tooltips/td-p/380022)